# Hybrid Plasma/laser weapon, what can be made into shared parts?

Tags: science-based, physics, weapons, engineering

In this world, the law enforcers and Military uses a new, multipurpose weapon which is basically a:

- [Free electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser), and a...
- [Railgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun)

Packed into a single weapon. However, when designing the weapon, it's important to determine the parts that can be interchangeable in these two systems, so the question is:

**What can be made into the shared parts of a free electron laser and a railgun, with nanotechnology?**

- Reversible, quick changes are allowed in the parts.

*This question is tagged science-based because both of these systems exist in real life.*

Comment: A coil gun typically shoots ferromagnetic projectiles, can you provide an example of one shooting plasma? Also a plasma is very different from a beam of electrons if I am not mistaken.

Comment: The battery pack?

Comment: @JoeKissling Well, [it's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_plasma_focus) close enough, but I still need the electrolaser to keep it alive. I recommend looking at the undulators.

Comment: In fact, I don't know if coilgun would even be practical for accelerating plasma. I think it would just end up compressing the plasma.

Comment: @JoeKissling Actually, [it's not so impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_railgun).

Comment: Rail Gun does not equal Coil Gun

Comment: @JoeKissling I know, but what's the core difference?

Comment: Principal of operation. Generally a coil gun needs a magnetic projectile to function because the coils generate an intense magnetic field that pulls (or pushes) the projectile along. Basically like magnets attracting or repelling one another. A rail gun uses a conductive projectile and the Lorenz force to accelerate a projectile. In a coil gun a plasma may just be compressed. See right hand rules

Comment: Are we talking hand-held or artillery piece here?

Comment: @Philipp Doesn't really matters, this time.

Comment: @JoeKissling Does, the self-containing magnetic field of the toroid plasma matter?

Comment: Yes. In that video it's hardly self containing, it's shrinking the entire time, cooling and expanding. It's only self containing in the sense the plasma is caught in a rotating toroid of air. Expose it the magnetic field of a coil gun and it will collapse, or dissipate.

Comment: @JoeKissling Is that true to railguns as well?

Comment: @RedactedRedacted No. The plasma should be accelerated down the barrel like any conductive projectile. The think is a rail gun is not as complex as a free electron laser. It only needs a capacitor bank and a switch to discharge it. Maybe an inductor for good measure, but a much simpler system all together.

Comment: @JoeKissling What would happen if there were an ionized path of air, nearby, that the plasma can follow?

Comment: I read the Title line ok, but did not understand the body of the post.  Two main parts?  But the title indicates they are two different systems, not parts of a whole.

Answer (score 1):

If you have nanotechnology, you won’t have “parts” in that sense.  As I elaborate in [this older post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/are-gunswords-feasible/53555#53555), you’ll have a lump of utility goo.  There may be specialized nanobots for some purposes like superconductors, but for the most part all the “goo” is a shared common component.